# iterate each element of a list and passing to a function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I want to iterate each element of a list and passing it to the function.
This is what i tried but getting below errors.

```
import call_functions
newObject = call_functions.call_functions_class()
size_DF = newObject.descr_size(sc, dataBase)
size_RDD = sc.parallelize(size_DF).map(lambda x : x[0])

def full_item_new(sc, dataBase, length, end_date):
    newObject.full_item(sc, dataBase, length, end_date)
size_RDD.map(lambda x : full_item_new(sc, dataBase, x[0], end_date)).collect()

def full_item(sc, dataBase, length, end_date):
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    insertDF = sqlContext.sql("insert into -----")
    return insertDF
```

**error** :

> "It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast "
>   Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the function `full_item_new`, it is difficult to answer but just looking at the args, you provide `sc` which is apparently your spark context variable. Therefore, it means you are trying to perform an action or transformation with `sc` while you are performing a transformation on your rdd. This is simply not possible.

`full_item_new` is executed on the workers but `sc` can only be used on the driver.

Comment: I have updated the question. full_item() we are inserting the data into a table.

Comment: Still, you cannot perform this action. You need to collect first, and then perform the insert. Or create a dataframe to insert, and then write it.